# Latin-1 Characters making Java program throw exception

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

I am currently working on a Java web app which at some point reads this xml data from database and tries to convert it to an Object using Java's **Unmarshaller** class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<knowledge idLog="1312" xmlns="http://www.testknowledge.it/knowledge">
    <knowledge_request code="REQUEST_CODE">
        <par type="continuo" data="08-02-2018 15:42:37" code="requestedfor_1" id="">
            <val>ÌÉÀÈÉĒ</val>
        </par>
        <par type="continuo" data="08-02-2018 15:42:37" code="requestedfor_2" id="">
             <val>ÌÉÀÈÉĒ</val>
        </par>
        <par type="continuo" data="08-02-2018 15:42:42" code="gender" id="">
            <val>M</val>
        </par>
    </knowledge_request>
</knowledge>
```

The piece of Java code that tries to convert the info stored in this xml is this:

```
public static Object str2obj(String  str) throws KnowdledgeException {
    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        Object o;
        o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
        return o;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new KnowdledgeException(e);
    }
}
```

The value of **str** is basically the above xml data read from database.
And the unmarshaller declaration:

```
static {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("it.health.knowledge.data");
            marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            // marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

            unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "There was a problem creating a JAXBContext object for formatting the object to XML.");
        }
    }
```

The exception that is raised when the function is applied on the xml data is: 
**[org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.]**

Any ideas on how to solve this problem is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `str.getBytes()` without charset. Try to write file you receive from DB to filesystem and verify it is in proper encoding, maybe the issue is before you even start parsing XML.

Comment: The data has some Latin-1 characters for example: è, à, ì and those are the characters that are breaking the program. Do you have any ideas on how to use charset with str.getBytes()? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(str))`.